# How can I configure Jenkins multibranch pipelines to use option with different args for branches & pull requests in a single Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

i am working on **declarative** jenkins multibranch pipelines and i would like to use

- `options { disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: false) }` when building **branches**
- and `options { disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true) }` when building **pull requests**.

[options](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options)

> disableConcurrentBuilds
>
> Disallow concurrent executions of the Pipeline. Can be useful for preventing simultaneous accesses to shared resources, etc. For example: options { disableConcurrentBuilds() } to queue a build when there’s already an executing build of the Pipeline, or options { disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true) } to abort the running one and start the new build.

Is it possible to configure Jenkins multibranch pipelines to use different arguments for disableConcurrentBuilds() options based on branch type in a single Jenkinsfile?

---

like it is possible in azure pipelines with [batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs) and [autoCancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multiple-pr-updates):

```
trigger:
  batch: true #waits until the run is completed, then starts another run
  branches:
    include:
      - main
pr:
  autoCancel: true #cancel in-progress runs for the same PR Defaults to true
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building pull requests, Jenkins defines an environment variable named `CHANGE_ID`. You can use it to set the boolean parameter:

```
options { 
    disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: env.CHANGE_ID ? true : false) 
}
```